# Redirect all pages except one to homepage via .htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I just trasformed an old website to a one-page Wordpress.

The old website had several URLS, now there's ony 1: the homepage.
Plus another page with privacy policy.

Hence I would like to redirect all URLS except the one with slug "privacy" to the homepage.

This is what I'm trying, without success:

```
#custom redirects
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/privacy-policy/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress (standard wp htaccess rules)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I get too many redirect: all urls redirect infinitely to themselves, why?

would be better (if possibile) using a redirect rule instead of a rewrite?

**UPDATE**

following comments suggestion I tried the following custom redirects (before WP standard rules):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/privacy-policy$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But still not working

Comment: that is probably what the `$1` does ;)

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/privacy-policy$   try this one

Comment: tried to remove the $1 as @MarkKaplun suggested, same result

Comment: @OwaisAlam I tried your suggestion too, still broken

Answer (score 3):

### Problems

> I get too many redirect: all urls redirect infinitely to themselves, why?

Apache rewrite rules are processed top-to-bottom, so your custom rewrite rule is always processed first. The `R` redirect flag instructs Apache to tell the browser to make a new request to the altered URL instead of serving the destination of the rewrite at the current address, and the `L` "last" flag tells Apache to ignore all proceeding rewrite rules - so whenever your `RewriteRule` is applied, a new request is made and your rules are processed once again from the top.

Your `RewriteCond` instructs Apache to process the proceeding `RewriteRule` whenever the request URI path does not begin with `/privacy-policy` - so virtually every request is resulting in a redirect before any of the other rules in your `.htaccess` can be so much as evaluated.

As @MarkKaplun alluded to in the comments `$1` is a back-reference that's substituted with the portion of the matched URI contained in the first "capture-group" (the first set of parenthesis in the pattern). Since `.*` literally matches any number of any characters, in your `RewriteRule` `$1` is substituted with the *entire* URI path.

In essence, your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/privacy-policy/
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

evaluate to *"If the URI does not begin with `/privacy-policy/`, have the web-browser send a new request to `http://www.mywebsite.com/(original URI path)`"*.

So, for illustrative purposes, say you navigated to `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/2015`; here's what happens with each request:

1. `/blog/2015` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/2015`.
2. `/blog/2015` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/2015`.
3. `/blog/2015` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/2015`.
4. [...]

Removing the `$1` back-reference from the `RewriteRule` is insufficient, as a URI path of `/` (or a simply empty one) still does not qualify as beginning with `/privacy-policy/`, resulting the in the behavior:

1. `/blog/2015` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`.
2. `/` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`.
3. `/` does not start with `/privacy-policy/`, tell the browser to go to `http://www.mywebsite.com/`.
4. [...]

You can verify this behavior by taking a look at your Apache installation's log files.

---

### Solution

If you don't plan on using WordPress's intended address routing, there's no reason to keep the default rewrite rules and stack more on top of them. Tailor them to your needs instead of adding complexity:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(/|index\.php)$ /index.php? [L]
RewriteRule ^/?privacy-policy/?$ /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /? [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

In summary,

1. .

   > **`RewriteRule ^(/|index\.php)$ /index.php? [L]`**
   >
   > If `/` or `index.php` was explicitly requested, serve `index.php`, but drop the querystring (in order to prevent changing pages via query-var manipulation) and stop processing rewrites.
2. .

   > **`RewriteRule ^/?privacy-policy/?$ /index.php [L]`**
   >
   > If `privacy-policy` (with or without leading and trailing slashes) was explicitly requested, serve `index.php` and stop processing rewrites.
3. .

   > ```
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   > RewriteRule . /? [L,R=301]
   > ```
   >
   > If the requested filename is not a file and not a directory, match a single character *anywhere* (in order to apply the rule no matter the URI) and tell the browser to make a new request to `/` and discard it's querystring. Stop processing rewrites.

It's worth noting that your intended outcome will probably produce a lot of unexpected behaviors - you'll likely be unable to access the administrative dashboard, for one. Attachments may also break. But the above should at the very least provide a good starting point for learning more about rewrite directives.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^/privacy-policy/? privacy-policy [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oldsite\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks @florian, but still not working, it keeps redirecting to the very same page i try to reach. No matter the URL, it redirects on itself infinitely. PS: why the ".html" extension?

Comment: Sorry, The '.html' is indeed obsolete. It sounds strange that you are still redirected infinitely. Most browsers store 301 redirects in the cache.  I would recommend using firebug for firefox. If you use FireBug, on the Network tab's drop down menu there is an option do disable the browser's cache.